# What is the best way to plot SODAR vertical wind profiles over time in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, metpy

I am able to do the typical wind barb and vector plots. I am looking to do a color contour kind of map and can't figure out how to do it. Does anyone have any ideas? Is there a package for this in MetPy? There are some examples in the article in the website below. I currently have my data in panda dataframes but I can ofcourse convert that to whatever is necessary.
https://asr.copernicus.org/articles/17/109/2020/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the standard `contour` plotting method from matplotlib. Here's a contour plot using some created synthetic data:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

z = np.linspace(0, 10000, 100)
t = [datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=15) * i for i in range(40)]
data = z[:, None] * np.arange(40)
plt.contour(t, z, data)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

This yields:

[image: time-based contour]

For the plots in the publication, that looks like something you'd want to use `pcolormesh` to accomplish:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

z = np.linspace(0, 10000, 100)
t = [datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=15) * i for i in range(40)]
data = np.random.randn(len(z), len(t))
plt.pcolormesh(t, z, data, shading='auto')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

This results in this image:

[image: time-based pcolormesh]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was really looking to make plots like the ones in the following link. Particularly the top two plots on the left hand side. https://asr.copernicus.org/articles/17/109/2020/asr-17-109-2020-f02-web.png

Comment: I added a sample of the same kind of data using `pcolormesh` instead of `contour`. To my eye, that looks like what you linked to.

Comment: Ah yes. That does look more like what I am looking for. I appreciate that, I will try it out, thanks again.